# radiobuttonlist with jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, validation

I have a radiobuttonlist like this and i am trying to make this a required field and am using form validation(jquery validation plugin).

```
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="PlateType1" runat="server" CssClass="rbclass required">
                    <asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Renewal</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Obviously behind the scenes, asp.net engine generates a table and so the form validation plugin does not understand the CssClass required function.So it never validates my list, though i dont select anything on submit.
How do i rewrite so that i can use jquery validation plugin?

my rbclass is

```
         .rbclass
           {
            float:left;
            display:block;

            }
```

On inspecting the elements through firebug, this is what is happening. The label class="error" is generated right after the radiobutton. How can i control that, so that it is after New.

```
             <td>
               <input id="MainContent_PlateType1_0" class="ui-wizard-content ui-helper-reset ui-state-default required error" type="radio" value="New" name="ctl00$MainContent$PlateType1">
               <label class="error" for="ctl00$MainContent$PlateType1" generated="true">This field is required.</label>
                <label for="MainContent_PlateType1_0">New</label>
             </td>
```

Here is my updated markup which references the generated id name

```
       <label for="PlateType1" class="rblabel">This plate is: <span class="required_field">*</span></label>
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="PlateType1" runat="server" CssClass="rbclass">
                    <asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Renewal</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:RadioButtonList> 
                 <span>
                  <label class="error" for="ctl00$MainContent$PlateType1" >Please select either New or Renewal</label>
                  </span>
```

Comment: What you want to validate? Is it simply validating that atleast one option is selected?

Comment: whether the radio button is checked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have something like this on document ready handler

```
$("#<%= PlateType1.ClientID %> input").addClass("required");
```

or if you want to have this inside an external js file

```
$(".rbclass input").addClass("required");
```

Comment: This sort of works..unfortunately what happens is the error message This field is required, push the Text New and Renewal to the next line. I would like to show the error message right next to the text New. Can i do something with my rbclass that would prevent this? i have added my rbclass on the top

Comment: Why do you want to show the required message next to "New"? The error message is for the radio button list and not for each individual input. Maybe I'm not getting your point

Comment: what i meant was show the error message to the right of the radiobuttonlist. It can be next to new or next to renewal or in between.Hope you get the point.

Comment: Please paste the real html of the radiobutton list and the required label so we can play a little with it on a jsfiddle

Comment: I was finally able to use a span tag and then use a label for to generate the error message in the place i want. I had to reference asp.net server control generated name to make it work. I have attached my code. If you know of a way to avoid the ctl$...name please let me know. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rbclass input').addClass('required') // or $('#PlateType1')...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some attributes the the Radiobuttonlist at runtime (data-type = radio, data-required=1

Then the below script vil validate(multiple) radiobuttonlist

```
   function validateRadioBoxes() {
        var isValid = true;
        var radioButtonLists = $('table[data-type="radio"][data-required="1"]');
        radioButtonLists.each(function (key) {
            isValid = ($(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").length>0);
            if (!isValid) {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**ASP Code:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
if( $("#rdbGender input:radio:checked").val()==undefined)    
alert("Please Select Gender");
```

Comment: Your answer looks better when formatting each code snippet in separate snippets.